# How to properly use the connection string?

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

my application is crashing when using this connection string:

```
protected string connectionString = @"Server=ricardo-pc\ricardo;Database=INSTANCIA_OBLI;Trusted_Connection=True;Provider=SQLOLEDB;";
```

it crashes at the `open()` function

```
OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conexion.Open();
```

the error is that the authorization is not valid...
before using `trusted connection = True` it complained about DNETLIB and that the server was not found..."

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect to that database using SQL Management Studio (from the machine where this code is crashing) - using a trusted connection?

Comment: could you give me an example of a connection string ? also tcp access is enabled